# Getting an issue record Highlights with Compact Layouts

Tags: lightning-experience, app-builder

I am getting an Issue with record Highlights with Compact Layouts when I edit the record detail page in Lightning app Builder It shows Person Account. but When I save the page It only shows Account in Highlights panel.Its working fine in Dev but  no in QA Org. I have checked all the recordtype, pagelayout setting , Profile permission, Lightning record page.
[image: Display Account]

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the screenshots for QA org as well?